# Automate Everyday Tasks in Mac Applications with Aliases in the ~/.bash_profile

Tags: macos, terminal, workflow, alias, bash

I know that you can create aliases in the `~/.bash_profile` that automate bash commands like:

```
alias fly="ssh username@ip_address -p22"
```

But I was wondering if it was possible to automate tasks within applications on the Mac.  So, for example, I know that you can make an alias to open the System Preferences:

```
alias sys="open /Applications/System\ Preferences.app/"
```

But how do you automate navigating within the System Preferences app?  For example, I find myself opening the System Preferences, typing 'network', and then pressing enter frequently to navigate to the Network settings.

Is there a way to automate these series of steps with an alias?  Or are aliases limited to bash commands?

Answer (score 3):

Shell aliases are limited to shell commands. But many OS X applications can be controlled by AppleScript commands, and those can be issued with the shell command `osascript`. Quoting gets a little tricky, though, because your AppleScript commands often contain quotes, which then need to be wrapped in another layer of quotes in the shell command, which then need to be wrapped in *another* layer of quotes when you define the alias.

See [macosxautomation.com](http://www.macosxautomation.com/) for notes on using AppleScript (and [this page](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/features/system-prefs.html) for System Preferences specifically). To get System Preferences to show the Network pane, you could use this AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.network"
    activate
end tell
```

...which can be issued with this `osascript` command (note that each line of the script corresponds to a `-e` argument, and the AppleScript double-quotes are wrapped in single-quotes for the shell):

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Preferences"' -e 'reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.network"' -e 'activate' -e 'end tell'
```

And you could create an alias for this:

```
alias networkprefs="osascript -e 'tell application \"System Preferences\"' -e 'reveal pane id \"com.apple.preference.network\"' -e 'activate' -e 'end tell'"
```

Note that I had to escape the double-quotes that're intended for AppleScript consumption... rather confusing. I'd use a shell function instead (similar to an alias, but without the quoting weirdness):

```
networkprefs() {
    osascript -e 'tell application "System Preferences"' -e 'reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.network"' -e 'activate' -e 'end tell'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this response!  Very helpful :)